# Decomposing react native component

Tags: react-native, components, decomposition

I've been trying to develop a react native app and I'm stuck here . I want to decompose onboarding component. Here is what I've done . Is it oke or what else can I do more readeble code ? I've divided Slider and SubSlider component but I think it isn't enough .Can I use component instead of functions Any suggestion will help me . What are the best practices in this case ? Thanks

```
const renderScrollView = (scroll, width: number, x: Animated.Value) => {
  return (
    <Animated.ScrollView showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} ref={scroll} pagingEnabled
      onScroll={Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x } } }], {
        useNativeDriver: true,
      })} 
      horizontal
   >
      {slides.map((data, index) => {
        return (
          <Slider key={index}>
            <SliderImage src={data.src} />
            <Box paddingHorizontal="l">
              <SliderTitle>{data.label}</SliderTitle>
              <SliderText>{data.description}</SliderText>
            </Box>
          </Slider>
        );
      })}
    </Animated.ScrollView>
  );
};

const renderSubSlider = (width: number,x: Animated.Value) => {
  return (
    <SubSlider>
      <SubSliderItem>
        {slides.map((_, index) => {
          return (
            <Dot
              key={index + 1}
              currentIndex={Animated.divide(x, width)}
              {...{ index }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </SubSliderItem>
   
    </SubSlider>
  );
};

const Onboarding = React.memo(({ onDone }: OnboardingProps) => {
  const { width } = useDimensions().window;
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const scroll = useRef(null);

  const x = React.useRef<Animated.Value>(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    x.addListener(({ value }) => {
      if (Math.ceil(value / width) === slides.length - 1) {
        setCompleted(true);
      } else {
        setCompleted(false);
      }
    });

    return () => x.removeAllListeners();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Box flex={1} backgroundColor="mainBackground">
      <Box flex={3}>{renderScrollView(scroll, width, x)}</Box>

      {renderSubSlider(width, x)}
    </Box>
  );
});
```

Comment: Does the code work? Do you get any error?

Comment: Yes,it works. I don't get any error

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I want to decompose of the component. I've explained already in the question

Comment: I think the code is pretty readable. You could turn your render functions into components that take props, but it wouldn't change the readability much in my opinion. Having said this I don't think this question, in its current state,  fits the site well as its a mostly opinion based question.